# How would I instantiate (run) a container stored in a private Gitlab container registry from Airflow? (from a hosted airflow service?)

Tags: gitlab, airflow, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, gitlab-ee

I want to create an Airflow DAG that fires once every 24 hours.

I want it to run a container on the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline (a container that is stored in the Gitlab container registry).

Ideally I would like the container to run on the Gitlab infrastructure (if that is possible), without having a repo there.

Any ideas on how this would be possible (with or without a repo there)?

The code is hosted on github.

Comment: please add more info, I believe you need to pull the image from private repo.